Cannot set onClick for listView items in a RemoteView
I'm working on a Todo List widget for my Android app. Each todo item features a "done" icon; when the user clicks it, I want to trigger an intent to a receiver that updates the database. I've created a ListView populated from my todo database, but I can't make the items clickable using any available options for RemoteViews. Here’s my code:
internal fun updateTodoWidget(
    context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int
) {
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.todo_widget)
    views.setRemoteAdapter(
        R.id.list, Intent(context, WidgetService::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId)
        }
    )
    views.setTextViewText(
        R.id.count, (context.readSharedPreference("todoCount", 0) as Int).toString()
    )
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}

class WidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent?): RemoteViewsFactory {
        return DataProvider(this, intent)
    }
}

class DataProvider(widgetService: WidgetService, val intent: Intent?) : RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private var myListView: MutableList<Todo> = ArrayList()
    private var mContext: Context? = null

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val view = RemoteViews(mContext!!.packageName, R.layout.todo_item_widget)
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.item_text, myListView[position].name)
        view.setOnClickFillInIntent(
            R.id.done, Intent(mContext, ActionReceiver::class.java).apply {
                action = "doneTodo"
                putExtra("id", myListView[position].id)
                putExtra("appWidgetId", intent?.getIntExtra("appWidgetId", 69) ?: 69)
            }
        )

//        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(
//            R.id.done,
//            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
//                mContext,
//                85,
//                Intent(mContext,ActionReceiver::class.java).apply {
//                    action = "doneTodo"
//                    putExtra("id",myListView[position].id)
//                    putExtra("appWidgetId",intent?.getIntExtra("appWidgetId",69)?:69)
//                },
//                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
//            )
//        )
        return view
    }
}

Here’s the layout for the todo item:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorOnSurface"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="Random task" />
</LinearLayout>

The receiver class is functioning correctly for other tasks, but it does not receive any intents when clicking the item.
I experimented with various intents, such as Activity intents, but it seems the ListView items aren't clickable.

There's a step missing, setPendingIntentTemplate(): https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections#behavior. For collection Widgets, you set a template PendingIntent on the AdapterView in the main RemoteViews, then the ones in the Factory just fill in the individual data.
